# How to include a prefix in a cross-reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, parts

I have two parts (Part A and Part B) in my paper, their theorems are called Theorem A and Theorem B, accordingly. The numbering in Part B again starts with 1.

I have a lot of cross-references between the two parts and thus need to include the prefixes A and B in the cross-references as follows:

> I would like to reference to items A1.1 to A1.3 and B1.1 to B1.3.

Unfortunately, using `\cref{en1,en2,en3,en4,en5,en6}` or `\labelcref{en1,en2,en3,en4,en5,en6}`,

> I only get a reference to items 1.1 to 1.3.

Is there a way to solve this?

Remark: The solution should still allow to work with `\value{}` and should not change the fact that the items themselves are only number as 1.1, 1.2, etc. and only the references are called A1.1, A1.2, etc.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\parindent0pt

\newtheorem{TheoremA}{Theorem A}
\newtheorem{TheoremB}{Theorem B}

\setlist[1]{leftmargin=*, label=\theTheoremA.\arabic*}
\setlist[2]{leftmargin=*, label=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[3]{leftmargin=*, label=\theenumi.\arabic*}

\begin{document}


\part*{Part A}

\begin{TheoremA}
This is the first Theorem in Part A.
\end{TheoremA} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{en1} First item in Theorem A1
\item \label{en2} Second item in Theorem A1
\item \label{en3} Third item in Theorem A1
\end{enumerate}


\setlist[1]{leftmargin=*, label=\theTheoremB.\arabic*}
\setlist[2]{leftmargin=*, label=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[3]{leftmargin=*, label=\theenumi.\arabic*}

\part*{Part B}

\begin{TheoremB}
This is the first Theorem in Part B.
\end{TheoremB} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{en4} First item in Theorem B1
\item \label{en5} Second item in Theorem B1
\item \label{en6} Third item in Theorem B1
\end{enumerate}

Here is a reference to items \labelcref{en1,en2,en3,en4,en5,en6} instead of items A1.1 to A1.3 and B1.1 to B1.3.

Here, there is again a reference only to \cref{en1,en2,en3,en4,en5,en6}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the theorems to be numbered with the A and B prefix? That way the when you cross-`\ref`erence them, it will include the same detail as the actual numbering. Otherwise, do you want the numbering to be without A and B prefixes, yet still have the cross-`\ref`erence include the prefix?

Comment: @Werner The theorems should be numbered with A and B (but I do not care if this is done automatically or if I have to do it manually), the items below a theorem must be numbered without the prefix. However, all references (to both theorems and items) should include the prefix.

Comment: Are you really referring to `\cref{en1,en2,en3,en4,en5,en6}`? That is, enumerations across theorems?

Comment: @Werner Yes, I have to reference to items from different theorems, even from the different parts - this is why I need the prefix to make these references clear

Answer (score 1):

You can add a prefix as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
```

I use that for my supplementary files. So tables and figures look like Figure S1, Figure S2, ..., Table S1, etc. 
You could wrap that around a macro that you use in place of `\part`, using `\newcommand`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that then the items under the theorem also have the prefix. However, I only want the prefix in the references to these items, not in the numbering of the items itself

Comment: I have just identified another problem with this solution: I have some macros that use `\value{Theorem}` - if I use the `\renewcommand{\theTheorem}{A\arabic{Theorem}}` they do no longer work with `\value`